# How to clear old Grid control?

Tags: vb6, grid, controls

What VB6 code will clear the contents of an old `Grid` control?

The `Grid` control is derived from `GRID32.OCX`. Here are the version details of this file:

[image]

The code provided here does not work: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/88911

Comment: Why doesn't the provided code work? What happens?

Comment: Strange results, keeps the content but inserts alternating blank lines.  I assume its because it is targetting a different implementation of `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

I fished `GRID32.OCX` out of my Visual Studio CDs, installed it and tried the process described at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/88911 .

Even though it is for a different version (and, yes, the version I installed is the one you've highlighted), it worked correctly for me (except that, as I have `Option Explicit` by default, I had to add `Dim i%, j%` at the start of the `Form_Load`).

Do you have code in the `RowColChange` or `SelChange` events that could be affecting the changes?